# Have custom functions and a task pane at the same time

Tags: ms-office, office-js, custom-functions-excel

I am following [this link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Custom-Functions) to try custom functions. The following manifest does enable the custom functions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>a124c024-2ae8-4d1a-bb00-7ff68c6fb738</Id>
  <!-- Generate a new guid for your Id element -->
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Custom functions sample" />
  <Description DefaultValue="A variety of sample custom functions." />
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Workbook" />
  </Hosts>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://www.myweb.com/customfunctions.html"/>
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="Workbook">
        <AllFormFactors>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="CustomFunctions">
            <Script>
              <SourceLocation resid="functionsjs" />
            </Script>
            <Page>
              <SourceLocation resid="functionshtml"/>
            </Page>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </AllFormFactors>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="functionsjs" DefaultValue="https://www.myweb.com/customfunctions.js" />
        <bt:Url id="functionshtml" DefaultValue="https://www.myweb.com/customfunctions.html" />
      </bt:Urls>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Now, I'm wondering if it is possible to have custom functions and a task pane at the same time. So I added `<body>this is the body</body>` in `https://www.myweb.com/customfunctions.html`. However, reloading the add-in does not make the task pane appear.

Could anyone tell me if it is possible to have custom functions and a task pane at the same time? what should I amend to enable this?

**Edit 1:** Changing `xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0"` to `xsi:type="TaskPaneApp"` does open the task pane, but when we try the custom functions, an error `We can't start this add-in because it isn't set up properly" is raised.

So I am still looking for a proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have custom functions and a task pane at the same time in the same add-in, by using add-in commands.

To enable a task pane command, use the `ShowTaskpane` action in your manifest (see the [help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-commands), like in this [sample manifest on GitHub](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Commands-Samples/tree/master/Excel)).

If you'd also like your task pane to be "permanent" whenever it's inserted, then use [this topic page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document) on automatically opening task panes.

-Michael (PM for custom functions)

Comment: Hello Michael, do you have any idea for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51239311/submit-add-ins-with-custom-functions-update)? Cheers

Comment: How would custom functions and task pane configuration appear in the manifest if we wanted to have them in the same add-in and control them from the same html and js files?